# How to get the caller filename in php?

Tags: php

I want to get the caller filename in PHP.

For instance:
I have a file "abc.php", which is having below code:

```
<?php
    header('location:xyz.php');
?>
```

In "xyz.php", I want to get the filename "abc.php"

```
<?php
    print (get_caller_function());
    
    function get_caller_function() {
        return __CALLER_FILE__;
    }
?>
```

What should I use in place of "**CALLER_FILE**" to get filename "abc.php"?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `basename(__FILE__, '.php')`

Comment: @SumitWadhwa, this will give me current filename (xyz.php in above scenario).
but I want caller file name (abc.php)

Comment: Can you give a few more details about what you're trying to achieve? It looks rather like this might be [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/237313) and the task you're actually trying to solve might have a different and more reliable solution.

Comment: The only one “calling” anything here – i.e., making the HTTP request – is the _browser_. At most you could look at the HTTP referrer here, but that is unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `sessions`.

In `abc.php` I would have:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['referrer'] = basename($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']); // SEE NOTE BELOW
header('location:xyz.php');
```

In `xyz.php`. I would use:

```
<?php
session_start();
print (get_caller_function());

function get_caller_function() {
    return $_SESSION['referrer'];
}
```

**NOTE**

To get the script name .. There are many ways to get what you want depending on your needs

```
basename($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];

basename(__FILE__, '.php');
```

The list goes on ..  But you can see the point ..

Comment: that can be the workaround but is there any built-in function to know the caller filename?

Comment: @Aj06 you can't possibly expect a php function on a redirect. you're redirecting. how would your server guess that unless you maintain some sort of state between your client and server

Comment: This is not a work around .. This would be the only proper way other than storing in a database or a file.  As @Sumit said, you can't expect a function from a redirect ..